# iOS: Require 3D Touch?

Tags: ios, 3d, touch, ios9

Has Apple documented any means (such as a UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key) for requiring 3D Touch on a device?

Am looking into things that will need 3D Touch.  Wouldn't be the best experience to run an alert telling the user their new app won't work...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you might not even see 3D Touch having a key in `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`. If that happens, it should be in a relatively long time until it is considered absolutely essential.

You should look at 3D Touch as a nice to have, not a mandatory capability.

If it enables certain features on your app, you need to make sure you have a fallback mechanism to access them when the capability is nonexistent.

Moreover, Users with a 3D Touch capable device can disable the feature in:

`Settings > General > Accessibility > 3D Touch`

So you should always code for both scenarios.

Think of it more like `TouchID` rather than like `Metal`. Even though nowadays almost everyone has an iOS device capable of using fingerprint scanning, people can still disable it and use a passcode. So if your app uses TouchID (e.g. most banking apps, Evernote, 1Password, etc) you still need a fallback.

Source: [Accessibility and Human Interface Guidelines for 3D Touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016543-CH1-SW1)

> To ensure that all your users can access your app’s features, branch your code depending on whether 3D Touch is available. See Checking for 3D Touch Availability.
>
> NOTE
>
> 3D Touch is available only on 3D Touch devices and when enabled. In iOS 9, 3D Touch is enabled by default. A user can turn off 3D Touch in Settings > General > Accessibility > 3D Touch.
>
> When 3D Touch is available, take advantage of its capabilities. When it is not available, provide alternatives such as by employing touch and hold.

Answer (score 0):

UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities is currently the only way to prevent customers from installing apps on a device that does not support certain capabilities by limiting them from installing from the App Store.

As of the time of this posting there is no key for 3D Touch, so your best option would probably be either putting it in the app description somewhere obvious, or as a warning in-app as you mentioned.

Hopefully they will add this key in the future, but I would assume that Apple's preferred usage of 3D touch is as a complementary but not necessary feature in iOS apps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if your app just doesn't work on all devices it can be downloaded on then they will reject it. Tell me if i'm wrong but Isn't it part of the review guidelines that the app work on all devices that can download it.

Answer (score -1):

Even though there is no 3D Touch in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities, the iPhone 6S and 6S Plus are the only iPhones to have 2 GB of RAM, the rest have at most 1 GB. So just make your app run on iPhones only and require 2 GB of RAM.

Comment: How do you restrict to devices with 2GB Ram using UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

Answer (score -1):

I also have a case that I want to show a menu tab for only 3DTouch devices.

For now, if a device without 3DTouch (EG iphone5) upgrades to iOS9.0, it will have 3DTouch enabled by default. When you read the value from traitCollection.forceTouchCapability, it tells you UIForceTouchCapabilityUnavailable. If you have a device with 3DTouch (which will also use iOS9), the value is UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable.

One other option is to use a third party class to know what device you are using. If it is iPhone6S or iPhone6S+, then return true for supporting3DTouch. But you have to manually update future iOS devices.